# Do I need to rebuild Qt on OS X in order to use C++11?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, c++11

I'm working with Qt Enterprise 5.3 on Mac OS X and I have downloaded the binary version which seems to be linked against libstdc++ as

```
otool -L /Users/Shared/Qt/5.3.1/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
```

shows

```
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

I was having some problems building my application, which I am porting from Windows, because libstdc++ would not support any C++11 features and using libc++ (via `make CXXFLAGS`) would result in  undefined symbols for STL itself. Finally I've found a solution, which was adding these two lines to my project file:

```
macx: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
macx: LIBS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++
```

The software now compiles and runs, but I am experiencing some weird crashes which do not happen on Windows (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with `EXC_I386_GPFLT`).

Is it possible that these errors are caused by the fact that my software and Qt are linked against different C++ libraries, so I need to rebuild Qt in order to use it, or should I rather be looking for bugs in my code?

Comment: I'm not sure about Clang, but in general it is not guaranteed to work when you do what you're doing.  That said, GCC handles is OK except for GCC 4.7.0 and 4.7.1 which had a nasty ABI-breakage for C++11 std::pair.

Comment: Just tried with gcc and the results are the same.

Comment: It would help if you can run in a debugger and give us some stack traces.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is guaranteed not ever to work correctly. Rebuilding Qt is rather trivial - do it first.